# Multiple sections repeating in TableView after tapping backline and letters quickly in a TextView inside a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitextview

When I tap letters in a TextView in a TableViewCell, the cell resize automatically.

Here is my tableView:[image]

The problem, is that when I put a section, for example "CONTACT" in that position of roll over at the top of the TableView like this, and I tap lots of backline and letters very quickly in the textView (inside the TableViewCell) 'Commentaire' like this:
[image]

I have problem of repeating sections in my tableview like this:
[image]

They are still present even if I reload the tableview.

I precise that the cell is sizing automatically with fiting with what is written in the TextView.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self updateFieldValue];

    //show/hide placeholder
    self.detailTextLabel.hidden = ([textView.text length] > 0);

    //resize the tableview if required
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    //scroll to show cursor
    CGRect cursorRect = [self.textView caretRectForPosition:self.textView.selectedTextRange.end];
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:[self.tableView convertRect:cursorRect fromView:self.textView] animated:YES];
}
```

How can I have a tableview that displays the cells correctly ?

Comment: Are you creating cells using storyboard or programmatically ?

Comment: I use it programmatically.

Comment: Did you use constraints for auto-sizing of cells

Comment: Nope, no constraints are used in the ViewController

Comment: Try to add top, bottom, leading, trailing constraint

Comment: The problem is that the textview is created programmatically. Is there a  way to add constraints programmatically ?

Comment: let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView,
                                         attribute: .leading,
                                         relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: cell.contentView,
                                         attribute: .leading,
                                         multiplier: 1.0,
                                         constant: 0.0), similarly do for trialing, top and bottom only changing the attribute :, and then add those constraint to cell.contentview

Comment: thanks, i am goin' to check it

Comment: Nope, it does the same...

Comment: did you set the text view translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

Comment: I just found the problem. It comes from the fact that I have to detect if the tableview animation is completed before to use beginUpdates. So I used the [CATransaction begin] etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add that lines that prevent if the animation is finished or not before begining opération;

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Perfect! You are a god